# can't delete document index in luence

Tags: java, lucene

I build a search index for luence like this:

```
Field idField = new Field("_id", "58369c7e0293a47b09d34605", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO);
Field tagField = new Field("tag", joinListStr(gifModel.getTags()), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
Field textField = new Field("text", gifModel.getText(), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
doc.add(idField);
doc.add(tagField);
doc.add(textField);
iwriter.addDocument(doc);
```

I want to delete that document by `Term` via the `_id` field acroding to [this article](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-delete-a-document-from-a-lucene-index-using-the-value-of-a-field.html):

```
public Map<String, Object> deleteIndexByMongoId(String id) {
        try {
            Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(GifMiaoMacro.LUCENE_INDEX_FILE));
            IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory);
            Term term = new Term("_id", id);
            int num = indexReader.deleteDocuments(term);
            indexReader.close();
            return new ReturnMap(num);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ReturnMap(GifError.S_DELETE_INDEX_ERR, "delete index error");
        }
    }
```

But here num allways is `0` and search result shows the document still in the search index, what have I missing?

### EDIT

change the `indexReader` to `indexWriter` still not working

```
public Map<String, Object> deleteIndexByMongoId(String id) {
        try {
            Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(GifMiaoMacro.LUCENE_INDEX_FILE));
            IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, new SmartChineseAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT));
            IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterConfig);
            Term term = new Term("_id", id);
            indexWriter.deleteDocuments(term);
            indexWriter.close();
            return new ReturnMap(0);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ReturnMap(GifError.S_DELETE_INDEX_ERR, "delete index error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

What version of Lucene are you using?? `IndexReader.deleteDocuments` no longer exists. It was depricated after Lucene 3.6. Either ways use the IndexWriter class.

```
    Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(GifMiaoMacro.LUCENE_INDEX_FILE));
    IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer());
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterConfig);
    Term term = new Term("_id", id);
    indexWriter.deleteDocuments(term);
```

[IndexWriter.deletedocuments(term)](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#deleteDocuments(org.apache.lucene.index.Term))

```
      Field idField = new Field("_id", "58369c7e0293a47b09d34605", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO);
```

Seems you have made the id field unindexable. So it cannot be searched, even if it is stored. You will have to use a field that is searchable from the index.

Comment: I am using lucene version 3.6.2

Comment: Does not really change the answer, you will still need to use IndexWriter class. I have changed the link to match your version's documentation.

Comment: thanks for reply @Sahil I have changed the reader to writer to perform a deleting action, but seems get no luck, result still the same, not deleted :(

Comment: Have you made an instance of the indexWriter class? Edit the question and put in the code you are using now.

Comment: please check the edit

Comment: I have changed the `_id` field as `Field idField = new Field("_id", gifModel.getId().toHexString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
` but still, can delete the item with that

Comment: Since when you were indexing, you had used Field.Index.NO, it doesnt matter now, you will have to do it when indexing. And btw, use Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED since you dont need to analyze the id feild.

Comment: Yes, I have re-create the index

Comment: now, I presume maybe it will be a bug for lucene 3.6.2 ? have been work around that all day :-(

Comment: I cannot say, maybe ask the solr user mailing list. I haven't used that version so don't know.